# Whats the best way to create a auto update solution for my WPF C# App?

Tags: c#, clickonce, auto-update

Im creating a simple alarm application which uses PNRP to send and recive alarms over the local network.
Now Im planning och implementing some auto update for this application and have looked at a few existing solutions.

The following is the requirements of the app.

1. It needs to allow network traffic in the Windows firewall for the executable file
2. It needs to put a shortcut in the Startup folder
3. It needs to be installed for everyone on the computer

This are the three primary requirements for the app.

So whats the best solution?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453005/best-practice-for-autoupdates, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691663/auto-update-library-for-net, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819647/auto-update-net-applications

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at a library I wrote and released as open-source to do just that transparently - including an external update application to do the actual cold update. See http://www.code972.com/blog/2010/08/nappupdate-application-auto-update-framework-for-dotnet/ and http://www.code972.com/blog/2011/06/some-updates-on-nappupdate/ for a sample of custom usage.

The code is at http://github.com/synhershko/NAppUpdate (Licensed under the Apache 2.0 license)

Comment: Thank you, will look in to that as soon as I have some time leftover from work.